# Using platformio with lib_deps per environment fails because non included file are being compiled when library in absent from lib_deps

Tags: c++, platformio

I'm using platformio for a project that has a few different environments each requiring their own specific libraries which are included in their lib_deps section of platformio.ini.  Only the class files needed are included via preprocessor directive based on a build flag for each environment.
example of the preprocessor included :

```
#elif defined(OLED64)
  #include "Displays/D_oledy64.h"
  using DisplaySubClass =  D_oledy64;
#elif defined(CHA)
  #include "Displays/D_ledfeather.h"
  using DisplaySubClass =  D_ledfeather;
```

When building CHA PIO still attempts to comile D_oledy64.cpp which includes the .h and includes a library that is not needed for CHA and so is not in CHA's lib_deps.  Compilation fails.

Is there anyway to tell pio to skip compiling files that are not specifically included in  current environment ?

Comment: [src_filter](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_build.html#src-filter) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following in platformion.ini

```
[env]
  framework = arduino
  upload_speed = 230400
  upload_port = /dev/cu.SLAB*
  monitor_port = /dev/cu.SLAB*
  src_filter =  
  +<*>
  -<.git/>
  -<.svn/>
  -<example/>
  -<examples/>
  -<test/>
  -<tests/>
  -<target/>
  -<Displays/*.cpp>
  +<Displays/Display.cpp>

[env:huzzah_NEOMATRIX]
  extends = huzzah_base
  build_flags = 
    ${huzzah_base.build_flags}
  -D NEOMATRIX

  src_filter = 
    ${env.src_filter}
    +<Displays/D_neomatrix*>
```